# Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected (CS0119) (MyFirstGame)

Tags: c#, monodevelop, monogame

I'm learning to program in C# using monodevelop and monogame.  I'm fairly familiar with C and Java but in honesty, I'm still learning to think like an Object Oriented programmer.  I wanted to use the following class to gather together relevant attributes of a sprite, together with methods to move, draw, accelerate, detect collisions etc. to tidy up the game code.  This class appears in a file SpriteObject.cs and compiles without errors on build.

```
namespace MyFirstGame
{
  class SpriteObject
  {
     private Texture2D Texture;
     private Vector2 Position;
     private Vector2 Velocity;

     public SpriteObject(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
     {
       this.Texture = texture;
       this.Position = position;
       this.Velocity = Vector2.Zero;
     }

     public SpriteObject(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, Vector2 velocity)
     {
       this.Texture = texture;
       this.Position = position;
       this.Velocity = velocity;
     }

     public Rectangle BoundingBox
     {
       get
       {
          return new Rectangle(
                     (int)Position.X,
                     (int)Position.Y,
                     Texture.Width,
                     Texture.Height);
       }
     }

     public void Move(SpriteObject sprite)
     {
     this.Position += this.Velocity;
     }

     public void BounceX(SpriteObject sprite)
     {
     this.Velocity.X *= -1;
     }

     public void BounceY(SpriteObject sprite)
     {
     this.Velocity.Y *= -1;
     }

     public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
     {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position, Color.White);
     }
  }
}
```

I'm am trying to use this class in the following code (which is a bastard mix of the untidy, but running, code I'm trying to clean up and the new class I'm trying to do it with).  Note particularly the lines marked with A> and B>.

```
    namespace MyFirstGame
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This is the main type for your game
        /// </summary>
        public class Game1 : Game
        {
            GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;              // All default to private
            KeyboardState oldKeyState;
            SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
            Boolean gameOn=true;    
A>          SpriteObject ballSprite, starSprite;         // A couple of sprites...
            Texture2D texStar, texBall;                  // This is a texture we can render.

            public Game1()
            {
                graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 900-32; // Force window size or it won't work...
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1600;    // Force window size
                Content.RootDirectory = "Content";              
                graphics.IsFullScreen = true;   
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
            /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
            /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
            /// and initialize them as well.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void Initialize()
            {
                // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
                oldKeyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                base.Initialize();

            }

            /// <summary>
            /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
            /// all of your content.
            /// </summary>
            // Set the coordinates to draw the sprite at.
            Vector2 starPosition = Vector2.Zero;
            Vector2 ballPosition = new Vector2(200, 0);

            // Store some information about the sprite's motion.
            Vector2 starSpeed = new Vector2(10.0f, 10.0f);
            Vector2 ballSpeed = new Vector2(10.0f, 0.0f);

            protected override void LoadContent()
            {
              // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
              spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
              texStar = Content.Load<Texture2D>("star");
              texBall = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ball");
B>            ballSprite = new SpriteObject(texBall, Vector2(200, 0), Vector2(10.0f, 0.0f));  // create two sprites
B>            starSprite = new SpriteObject(texStar, Vector2.Zero, Vector2(10.0f, 10.0f));
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
            /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
            protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
            {
              // Move the sprite by speed.

              KeyboardState newKeyState = Keyboard.GetState();
              if (newKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

              if (collisionDetected()) gameOn = false; // If there's a collision then no movement.

              //Could do with putting this in a seperate method or class, if there isn't one already...   
              if (gameOn)
              {
                  if (newKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.PageUp) && oldKeyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.PageUp))
                  {
                    starSpeed.X *= 1.1f;
                    starSpeed.Y *= 1.1f;
                  }
                  else if (newKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.PageDown) && oldKeyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.PageDown))
                  {
                    starSpeed.X *= 0.9f;
                    starSpeed.Y *= 0.9f;
                  }
                 else if (newKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && oldKeyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Up))
                  {
                    starSpeed.Y += 1.0f;
                  }
                 else if (newKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) && oldKeyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Down))
                  {
                    starSpeed.Y -= 1.0f;
                  }
                 else if (newKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && oldKeyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Left))
                  {
                    starSpeed.X -= 1.0f;
                  }
                 else if (newKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) && oldKeyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Right))
                  {
                    starSpeed.X += 1.0f;
                  }
                  oldKeyState = newKeyState;

                  starPosition += starSpeed;
                  ballPosition += ballSpeed;

                  int MaxX =
                    graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - texStar.Width;
                  int MinX = 0;
                  int MaxY =
                    graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - texStar.Height;
                  int MinY = 0;

                  // Check for ball bounce
                  if (ballPosition.X > MaxX) 
                  {
                    ballPosition.X = MaxX;
                    ballSpeed.X *= -1;
                  }
                  if (ballPosition.X < MinX) 
                  {
                    ballPosition.X = MinX;
                    ballSpeed.X *= -1;
                  }
                  if (ballPosition.Y > MaxY)
                  {
                    ballSpeed.Y *= -1;
                    ballPosition.Y = MaxY;
                  }

                  ballSpeed.Y += 1;

                  // Check for bounce.
                  if (starPosition.X > MaxX)
                  {
                    starSpeed.X *= -1;
                    starPosition.X = MaxX;
                  }

                  else if (starPosition.X < MinX)
                  {
                    starSpeed.X *= -1;
                    starPosition.X = MinX;
                  }

                  if (starPosition.Y > MaxY)
                  {
                    starSpeed.Y *= -1;
                    starPosition.Y = MaxY;
                  }

                  else if (starPosition.Y < MinY)
                  {
                    starSpeed.Y *= -1;
                    starPosition.Y = MinY;
                  }
                }
              else
                {
                  starSpeed=Vector2.Zero;
                  ballSpeed=Vector2.Zero;
                }
            }

            private Boolean collisionDetected()
            {
                if (((Math.Abs(starPosition.X - ballPosition.X) < texStar.Width) && (Math.Abs(starPosition.Y - ballPosition.Y) < texBall.Height)))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
            protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
            {
              graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

              // Draw the sprite.
              spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
              spriteBatch.Draw(texStar, starPosition, Color.White);
              spriteBatch.Draw(texBall, ballPosition, Color.White);
              spriteBatch.End();

              base.Draw(gameTime);
            }

        }
    }
```

A>  Marks where the new `SpriteObject ballSprite, starSprite;` are declared without any problems.

B>  Marks where errors arise as I try to use the SpriteObject constructor to create and assign a value to my previously declared SpriteObjects - the errors as per the title of the post.  Two such for the first line and one for the second.

The namespace hints at my level of experience with C#.  If you could help me understand my almost certainly basic mistake I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two lines of code you indicated are missing the ['new' operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx), which is required to instantiate the `Vector2` (or any) class.

```
ballSprite = new SpriteObject(texBall, new Vector2(200, 0), new Vector2(10.0f, 0.0f));

starSprite = new SpriteObject(texStar, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(10.0f, 10.0f));
```

Comment: A schoolboy error.  Thank you for pointing out what I could not see and punting me further up the learning curve.